# No connectivity from Broadcom 4322

Tags: wireless, networking, laptop

While browsing the web I was notified that my Dell Vostro 1720 was offline.  After no luck rebooting my D-Link Verizon WiFi router, I saw my laptop could not connect wirelessly to anything, even a USB dongle.  I can only connect to a wired connection now. Where do I start in diagnosing this?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Thanks, Wild Man! I'll do this & post the results here on Sunday.

Comment: Wild Man (or anyone else who my be able to understand this), here is the link to the diagnosis of the wifi issue:  http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7826786/

Comment: Did you manually install the driver? It shows a hard block is your physical switch off?

Comment: If you tried the answer below you will need to remove the b43 driver before we continue. b43 partially supports your device but not completely.

Comment: I just copied & pasted the string below into a terminal.  I don't know if it removed the b43 driver...and I don't know how to do it if it did not.  I did not see a physical switch for the wifi on the laptop either...maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

Comment: @WildMan I think I may have one of my badges taken away...!  This laptop was given to me a few months ago & I was completely unaware it had a switch for wifi!  Lo & behold when I examined the box intently, there it was..."OFF"!  Thanks you so much for the help!  I wish I had posted this before I stayed up until 1:30am trying to figure it out over the weekend.

Comment: When i get home i will make this my answer so you can accept it. Glad it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information from the script that you posted your wifi is hardblocked that usually means the switch is physically off and needs turned on.

Some computers have a switch, others the wifi is turned on with the fn key + f2 or some other key similar.

Answer (score 0):

Install the device driver package:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

If already installed, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove firmware-b43-installer && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: I tried both of these & neither was successful.  Thanks for the info, though!